# How to search for multiple keywords using sql search

Tags: php, sql

I have a current SQL search query that lets users enter keywords to search for my SQL database. At the moment, the search will work with multiple words, but will show all results for either keyword. If you type in "Ford Mustang" it will show all results that have either "Ford" or "Mustang", but I need it to only show results that show both "Ford" and "Mustang".

What I have tried is below

```
public function getProductByName($name){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE name REGEXP :names');
    $names = "[[:<:]](" . str_replace(" ", "|", $name) . ")[[:>:]]";
    $stmt->execute(array('names' => $names));
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (REGEXP is usually a bit product specific.)

Comment: Duplicate your questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704735/how-to-search-for-multiple-keywords-in-sql

Comment: I am using mySQL and am using PHP on my server to do the actual search function

Comment: Au Nguyen, that post does not answer my question

Answer (score 1):

maybe this what you're looking for

> select * from example where name like "%mustang%ford%"

Comment: I need to do it in PHP as per the above sample code. Also, the actual search terms will vary depending upon user input

Comment: put the query inside $stmt, and if u want to use user input, then u can pass $name to query
something like this 
 `$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE name like "%' .$name.%"');`

Comment: I have tried that way and it works, but only in word order, ie if user puts "Ford Mustang" then it will search for Ford and Mustang in that order. If the data was "the ford was a mustang" it will not show search results because Ford and Mustang are not text to each other

Comment: `select * from example where name REGEXP "^(?=.*ford)(?=.*mustang).*$" `

change ford and mustang with input.
`^ means start of line,
$ means end of line,
?= means lookahead,
.* means match any characters`

Comment: **edit** : add `?` before `ford/mustang(input)` to make it lazy search, so it will stop searching when find `input`
`select * from example where name REGEXP "^(?=.*?ford)(?=.*?mustang)"`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query

```
select * from tbl_products where name like "%Mustang%" and name like "%ford%";
```

PHP code

```
//you may split search string like
$searchArray = explode(' ', $name);

//for loop for preparing the query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE ';
$searchParams = array();
$conditions = [];
for($searchArray as $searchStr){
    $conditions[] = 'name like ?';
    $searchParams[] = "%$searchStr%";
}

//attach the conditions
$query .= implode(" and ", $conditions);

//execute the query 
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute($searchParams);
```